# Get date from <td> if there is one

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple table rows. The table cell with class "dates" can contain a date or the value "Permanent". If there is a date and this is greater than today's date, it should be colored in red.

I tried (but won't work):

```
if(($(".dates").getDate() < new Date()) != -1)  {
        $(".dates").style.color = "green";
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Permanent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Permanent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2.05.2015</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show your sample html with values

Comment: $(".dates").getDate() i don't think this correct

Comment: Please show more of your code? What format are your dates in?

Comment: Is `getDate` a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".dates").each(function(){
  
  if(new Date($(this).html()) < new Date())  {
        $(this).css("color", "green");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>abc</td>
   <td class="dates">2016-10-10</td>
   <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>abc</td>
   <td class="dates">2016-09-10</td>
   <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>abc</td>
   <td class="dates">2016-08-10</td>
   <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>abc</td>
   <td class="dates">2016-11-10</td>
   <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you're dealing with properly formatted dates, or use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). If you're dealing with proper dates you can use `new Date()` to compare the dates in the cells to today's date, and apply some CSS conditionally.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date').each(function(){
    if (new Date($(this).text()) > new Date()) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td class="date">Tue Oct 04 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Mon Oct 03 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Fri Oct 07 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Mon Oct 03 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Permanent</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Sat Oct 05 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Sun Oct 07 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Mon Oct 08 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Tue Oct 09 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Permanent</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="date">Wed Oct 10 2016 01:24:37 GMT-0600 (MDT)</td></tr>
</table>
```